# How should technically incorrect answers be dealt with?

Tags: discussion

Can I use the Meta site to discuss technically incorrect answers so that the the community could reach a consensus that the answer was incorrect and appropriate action can be taken?

Comment: Usually this happens with hot network question posts

Comment: The ability for 100 score site-wide-bonus users to _upvote_ but not _downvote_ is really damaging to this site.

Comment: If you ever see a hnq question that isn't benefiting the site flag it

Comment: Explain clearly what is wrong in a comment, and then watch Voltage Spike move the explanation to chat when the original author digs in deeper on their error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things one can do on technically incorrect posts:

1. Ask the OP to change the post.
2. <s>Edit the post yourself (usually not a good idea to completely rearrange a post).</s> *nope, that's not allowed, unless the "error" is an obvious mistake like a typo*
3. post your own answer
4. Downvote the post.

Keep in mind that technically incorrect means different things to different people. The first thing to do would be to use the comment system and try to correct the post that way.

If you do wish do discuss questions on the meta realize that it's a slower process than the steps above

Comment: Sometimes the user who has posted the wrong answer won't come online. I have already left a comment. But is it appropriate to discuss other's answers here on Meta?

Comment: Yes, you can if you wish, you'll get better milage if the other options are tried first

Comment: **Edits are only for little things, like obvious typos, they may not alter the basic meaning!**   It's very sad to see  moderator *still* recommending an action that is a rule violation, especially when that moderator has been previously reminded of this very rule.  The issue is not "rearranging" but rather _meaning_.   Though technically it is _possible_...

Comment: I agree with Chris Stratton here.